# Multi-criteria sorting/distribution into sets

Tags: algorithm, sorting, distribution

I'm trying to figure out an algorithm...

Input is a bunch of objects that have multiple values (eg 3 values per object, colour/taste/age, though it could be more).

The algorithm would then distribute the objects into a pre-defined number of sets. Each set should end up with almost the same number of objects (preferably the object count per set shouldn't differ more than 1), and achieve the objective of as fair a distribution of values per set as possible (eg try to have close to as many red in each set, and same for other colours, as well as tastes and ages, etc).

Values are tied to objects and cannot be changed. If you move an object from one set to another it brings all its values.

I found this related question: [Algorithm for fair distribution of numbers into two sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507830/algorithm-for-fair-distribution-of-numbers-into-two-sets)

and the "number partitioning problem" suggested seems to help with single value distributions, but I'm looking for information/algorithms with multiple values per object (as described above).

Also note that the values cannot be normalized, ie each object cannot be totalled up into a single value.

Thank you kindly for any assistance.

Comment: Which has precedence? Having equal numbers of objects or equal numbers of each value? Do any of the values take precedence over the others?

Comment: Preferably both objectives are satisfied, if necessary the equal number of objects constraint could be relaxed slightly but not too much (maybe a difference of up to 2 or 3). Fair distribution of values is likely not going to be perfect anyway, so it has wiggle room (maybe something like 10% of totals). Really just need to get something reasonably close. The values have no precedence over other values.

Comment: I think that trying to satisfy both requirements at the same time could be pretty difficult. Assigning precedences to different criteria makes the job easier, but what you want will probably require some sort of heuristic algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you should approach this as a clustering problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis .

Comment: +1 for a good starting point.  It's almost the exact opposite of clustering though.  Maybe once you have the clusters, take equal amounts from every cluster to make the result sets.